# Cumulative distribution of mixed random variable function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Random variable $X$ has probability density function:
$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2e^{−2x}, & \text{for } x\geq 0,\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Furthermore, the random variable Y is defined as
$$
Y = 
\begin{cases}
2X, & \text{if } X < 1/2,\\
0, & \text{if } X\geq 1/2.\\
\end{cases}
$$
Determine the cumulative distribution $F_Y(y)$ of the random variable $Y$.

How do I solve this question? If $Y$ was simply defined as $Y=2X$ then it would simply be finding $P[Y\leq y]=P[2X\leq y]=P[X\leq y/2]$ and thus solving the integral
$$
\int^{y/2}_0{2e^{-2x}}dx
$$

Comment: Note $Y$ is supported on $[0,1)$. Try and show for $y\in [0,1)$ that $$\mathbb{P}\left(Y\leq y \right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq \frac{y}{2}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Also note: this means that $\Bbb P(Y=0) = \Bbb P(X\geq 1/2)$ so there is a massive step in the CDF for $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on basic principles. Note that $Y$ is of the form

$$ Y = g(X), \qquad \text{where} \quad g(x) = \begin{cases}
2x, & \text{if $x < \frac{1}{2}$,} \\
0, & \text{if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$.}
\end{cases} $$

From this and using the definition of CDF,

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y)
&= \mathbf{P}(Y \leq y)
= \mathbf{P}(g(X) \leq y).
\end{align*}

So the problem boils down to solving the inequality $g(x) \leq y$ for each given $y$. To this end, you may study the behavior of the function $g(x)$. Note that the graph of $g(x)$ looks like:

[image: graph of]

From this, we can solve the inequality $g(x) \leq y$ for $x$ for each given value of $y$:

| Range of $y$ | Sol. of $g(x) \leq y$ | $F_Y(y)$ | Graph |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $y < 0$ | $x \leq y/2$ | $\begin{aligned} \mathbf{P}(X \leq y/2) = 0 \end{aligned}$ | [image: graph 1] |
| $0 \leq y < 1$ | $x \leq y/2$ or $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ | $\begin{aligned} &\mathbf{P}(X \leq y/2) + \mathbf{P}(X \geq \tfrac{1}{2}) \\ &= 1 - e^{-y} + e^{-1} \end{aligned}$ | [image: graph 2] |
| $y \geq 1$ | $x \in \mathbb{R}$ | $1$ | [image: graph 3] |

Summarizing, the CDF of $Y$ is given by

$$ F_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
0, & y < 0, \\
1 - e^{-y} + e^{-1}, & 0 \leq y < 1, \\
1, & y \geq 1.
\end{cases} $$

For fun, I also included the graph of $F_Y$ below:

[image: graph of CDF of Y]

Comment: Thanks, the figures really helped me understand!

Comment: @Aycapitan, Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

In these cases it is advisable to use the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
which allows to easily manage propositions (in our case intervals).
Alternatively you can use Bolean Algebra if you are more familiar with.

So we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & Y = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {2X} \hfill & {\left| {\left( {0 \le } \right)X < 1/2} \right.} \hfill  \cr 
   0 \hfill & {\left| {1/2 \le X} \right.} \hfill  \cr 
 } } \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad Y = 2X\left[ {0 \le X < 1/2} \right] = 2X\left[ {0 \le X} \right]\left[ {X < 1/2} \right] =   \cr 
  &  = 2X\left[ {0 \le X} \right]\left( {1 - \left[ {1/2 < X} \right]} \right)
 = 2X\left[ {0 \le X} \right]\left( {1 - \left[ {1/2 \le X} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 2X\left( {\left[ {0 \le X} \right] - \left[ {1/2 \le X} \right]} \right) \cr} 
$$

So for instance we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Pr \left( {Y \le y} \right) = \Pr \left( {2X\left[ {0 \le X} \right]\left[ {X < 1/2} \right] \le y} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \Pr \left( {\left[ {0 \le X} \right]\left[ {X < 1/2} \right]\left[ {X \le y/2} \right]} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {y/2 < {1 \over 2}} \right]\Pr \left( {\left[ {0 \le X} \right]\left[ {X \le y/2} \right]} \right) \cr} 
$$

But .. there is some normalization to carry out on your starting equality.